# What is the control that places Work phone in the visible part of the profile and leave others in the 'show more'?

Tags: 2013, user-profile, user-profile-property

I am trying to bring other standard properties and one custom property (phone extension) in the visible part of the profile and I can't understand what is the command that places work phone, job title and office in the visible part and others in the 'show more' part.

I do not want to show them all, just bring office and work phone in the 'show more' and bring up other 2 details.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking, I have been meaning to do more investigation as part of some programming tasks that I am working on and this is a timely inquiry. I have seen other questions in a similar vein and since the first answer missed the mark, here goes. (BTW, I tried an honest answer in the past and got voted down. Don't shoot the messenger.)

**You Can't**

Sure, you can do the hide and show trick, but the real problem is that the Profile Info Web part (Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileInfoWebPart) is lame and limited. It will NEVER do what you really want. Admit it...you don't want to **just** show properties, you want to:

- Show the properties you want
- In the order you want
- With hyperlinks to the locations you want (like clickable email addresses)
- With a collapsible section containing the properties you want

Right?

In order to do that you have to do some programming. It's SUPER easy, In fact, you can do it all client-side, so it'll work in Office 365. I am working on a sample and if I can get past an issue with MDS I'll update this answer.

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 properties in User Profile Services Work phone,Department and Title which are visible on the Profile. So you can work around with it.

You can edit the User Properties :

Manage User Properties
[image]

Edit the property and set the New Mapping as required and remove the other if not required:

[image]

Comment: and those cannot be replaced by country, phone extension?

Comment: what do you need here exactly, there are many properties. you can just check them all in user profile services and manage your profile data easily.

Comment: Not true. There are some properties that show up by default, some others you add are added only in the portion SHOW MORE (below). I want to know if it easily possible to show one property in the portion above, in addition or replacing an existing one.

Comment: what i see when editing a profile is Basic Information, Contact Information, Details three sections. So here details which are in Basic Information will be displayed to everyone by default and Contact Information and Details section we can set it to "Only Me" drop down option instead of "Everyone" which would not show the property. I hope we are on same lines.

Comment: You do not understand what I am talking about

Comment: sorry for that. can you please explain it?

Comment: it's the area on the side of the page, not on the main page and they are immediately visible, you do not have to click details, contact information. You only have to click show more, but the 3 fields (job title, telephone and company) are visible

Comment: i see job title, department, email, phone and office location by default and when i say show more i get mobile, fax, home phone, past projects, skills

Comment: exactly, I want to know how to place IPphone (we have a value) instead of phone. Right now it is below SHOW MORE

Comment: edit in my answer. kindly refer

Comment: I have done the above and it shows up the property BELOW the "show more". You are still not getting what I want to do. Let's end it here.